# grep + regex: how to write pattern for matching data with context sensitive elements?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Suppose there is a text (assembly code)

```
st.w    av,d15
ld.w    d15,av
```

Suppose we want to match it with grep. We can use this pattern:

```
pattern=\
'\s+st.w\s+av,.*'\
'\s+ld.w\s+.*,av'
```

Note: we use `.*` to match the register names. In the future these register names can change.

Suppose we want to use special regex for register names.
We add special `@reg` keyword:

```
pattern=\
'\s+st.w\s+av,@reg'\
'\s+ld.w\s+@reg,av'
```

Then we add a prepossessing function for the grep pattern, where we replace all the special keywords to actual regex patterns:

```
preprocess_pattern () {
    local result=$1
    # Replace @reg to exact regex pattern [a..d][0..15].
    result=${result//'@reg'/'[a-d](1[0-5]|[0-9])'}
    # Add other replacements (if need).
    #result=${result//''/''}
    echo "$result"
}
```

Then we call `preprocess_pattern()` before executing `grep`:

```
pattern="$(preprocess_pattern $pattern)"
if ! grep -Pzo $pattern code.asm > /dev/null
then
    echo "grep #$i failed (pattern: "$pattern")"
    ((++failed))
fi
```

It works, but we want more.

We want to add `@preg`, which is *previous register*.

```
pattern=\
'\s+st.w\s+av,@reg'\
'\s+ld.w\s+@preg,av'
```

Now the question: where is (and how) to add the logic, which after the each occurrence of `@reg` *saves* the matched value (in our case `d15`) in the special stack / buffer and after each occurrence of the `@preg`  *retrieves* the matched value from the stack / buffer and checks this value against the value of the `@preg`?

In other words: how to write pattern for matching data with *context sensitive* elements? Is it possible at all with grep?

If yes (i.e. possible) then how to describe this *context sensitivity* in the pattern?

If no (i.e. impossible) then how else to solve this challenge?

Comment: you won't be able to do it like this this. each line is matched _independently_

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve might be achievable by grep + regex, but that's going to be complicated. Your task needs a full fledged script or a program in some language.

Following features of different commands can be helpful

1. Grep Context: the only context grep provides is number of lines `before` and `after` a matched line [`-A`, `-B`, `-C` (combination of previous two)]
2. Awk and Sed : using these you can search for text within 2 patterns.

But again, this is going to be complicate. From what I understand, you are trying to write a parser of somekind, so you should research and try to use the write tool before jumping into writing complicated commands.